# OData Associations In C#

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

I was reading about OData sources at Odata.org when I ran across this segment about associations.

> Associations define the relationship between two or more Entity Types
>   (for example, Employee WorksFor Department). Instances of associations
>   are grouped in Association Sets. Navigation Properties are special
>   properties on Entity Types which are bound to a specific association
>   and can be used to refer to associations of an entity.
>
> Finally, all instance containers (Entity Sets and Association Sets)
>   are grouped in an Entity Container.
>
> Putting the above paragraphs into OData terms, the feeds exposed by an
>   OData service are represented by Entity Sets or a Navigation Property
>   on an Entity Type that identifies a collection of entities. For
>   example, the Entity Set identified by the URI
>   http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products or the collection
>   of entities identified by the "Products" navigation property in
>   http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products
>   identifies a feed of entries exposed by the OData service.

I am making a OData service in C# using Visual Studio 2012 and would like to use the URL functionality mentioned. However I do not know how to set it up. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
    public class AssociationTest : DataService<ServiceContext>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
public class ServiceContext
{
    CategoryList _categories = new CategoryList();
    public IQueryable<Category> CategorySet
    {
        get{return _categories.AsQueryable();}
    }
    ProductList _products = new ProductList();
    public IQueryable<Product> ProductSet
    {
        get{return _products.AsQueryable();}
    }

}
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("ID")]
public class Category
{
    public string Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class CategoryList : List<Category>
{
    public CategoryList()
        : base()
    {
        Add(new Category { Type = "Hardware", ID = 0 });
        Add(new Category { Type = "Software", ID = 1 });
    }
}
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("ID")]
public class Product
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int CategoryID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class ProductList:List<Product>
{
    public ProductList()
        : base()
    {
        Add(new Product { Name = "Computer", ID = 0, CategoryID = 0 });
        Add(new Product { Name = "Phone", ID = 1, CategoryID = 0 });
        Add(new Product { Name = "Outlook", ID = 2, CategoryID = 1 });
        Add(new Product { Name = "Excel", ID = 3, CategoryID = 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: The paragraph can be found at http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/overview/

Comment: Are you using WCF Data Services, ASP.NET Web API, or making an OData server by hand?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then I think what you want will just work out of the box. For example, if you are using Entity Framework as your provider, following the quick start guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728275(v=vs.103).aspx) should result in a service that generates payloads with navigation links like the one in the text you copied. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It is the same idea except I don't want to base my DataService off of an Entity Data Model. I am trying to base it off a class containing IQueryable lists. I'll include some of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modeling the relationship between Product->Category with a foreign key, you could have your service model point to the product's category directly. What I mean is that instead of this:

```
public class Product
{
    // ...
    public int CategoryID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You could model it like this:

```
public class Product
{
    // ...
    public Category ProductCategory
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If you set up the model this way, the WCF Data Services reflection provider should automatically create a navigation property on Product as well as the necessary association in the model.